# Ubuntu 16.04 custom xsession gnome-session hangs

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd

I am trying to set up a custom xsession on Ubuntu 16.04. I need to run some custom setup before starting gnome-session. I have successfully done this on Ubuntu 12 but porting across to 16.04 results in a blank screen on login. After tracking through what is happening I have discovered that `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` is hanging when it is called from anywhere, other than the `Exec=` clause in `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop`.

This can easily be demonstrated by creating a script

/usr/share/xsessions/start.sh:

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

And changing the `Exec=` line in `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` to:

```
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/start.sh
```

The result is that the session will hang when you try to log in. `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` is being started, but it hangs somewhere.

Am I missing some 'apparmor' or other security magic that might be getting in the way here?

I am at a loss as to what is going on. Even simply changing the name of `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` to `/usr/share/xsessions/my.desktop` (with the original `Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu` unchanged) results in gnome-session hanging.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Richard

--- Update

More digging reveals that at least symptom is that the following processes are running when the working configuration is used, but are not present when the `start.sh` script is used:

```
 1 14628 14628 14546 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00 /sbin/upstart --user
14628 14639 14638 14638 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00  \_ upstart-udev-bridge --daemon --user
14628 14650 14650 14650 ?           -1 Ss    1000   0:00  \_ dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-pVN8SJdGnw
14628 14662 14662 14662 ?           -1 Ss    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/window-stack-bridge
14628 14691 14690 14690 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00  \_ upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-name session
14628 14694 14693 14693 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00  \_ upstart-file-bridge --daemon --user
14628 14695 14692 14692 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00  \_ upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system
14628 14701 14650 14650 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
```

I guess this points to something in the systemd -> upstart magic.

Comment: Perhaps this was caused by not using `exec` to call `gnome-session`, so that it replaces its parent?